# How can I set up a color them for french algorithm in Sublime Text

Tags: syntax, sublimetext3, color-scheme

I'm currently studying on a short project (for school) where I need to write an algorithm (in French btw).

I'm writing it in Sublime Text (because of my background with HMTL), and I would like to have a coloration on some words that I would define (such as 'Type', 'Fonction') in French.

Some people told me it was possible but I don't know how :/
Could anyone tell me the way we can do it ?

[Here is an image of a part of my algorithm in french][1]
in this exemple I would like to have 'Fonction' in red, everything that is being // in light grey (...)

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5hy8.png

Comment: You need to write a language syntax that recognizes your keywords. Check out the [Syntax Definitions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html) and [scope naming guidelines](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html) pages in the official documentation.

Comment: That being said, Stack Overflow is neither a discussion forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as [ask]. Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).